# Eclipse Juno wont start and it has no error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Can anyone please help me what to do with this? My eclipse wont open. I already downloaded multiple files from the internet and yet it's still the same. No errors are found since it wont start.

Comment: Won't open??. Won't start??   Can you  describe what is happening. For  your question, my answer would be, "you need to double click in exe file to start.".    Make sure you have java 8 installed in your machine

Comment: @KarthikRocky I already double clicked the eclipse.exe but it wont open.

Comment: Any luck with java 8.  Do you see .log file in eclipse installed location

Comment: It's still the same. I already installed the java 8.

Comment: @KarthikRocky oh i found the error it says. "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM"

Answer (score 0):

So From the comments above what i can see is you have download the 64 bit eclipse version although you have 32 bit architecture. So I recommend you to download the 32 bit version of Eclipse.

NOTE : Luna is the latest version of Eclipse.

Following is the link.

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR2/eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32.zip

Answer (score 0):

Download 64 bit java 6 or 7 version and install it. It would solve your problem